# How can I use Windows 7 API to perform simple database queries on CSV files through Excel VBA?

Tags: windows-7, excel, vba

I'm working with CSV transaction data files that are 350 mb+ and 1,100,000+ lines each.

I was wondering how can I perform some simple fast queries on these files through the VBA IDE, save the CSV, and then open the result as a workbook in Excel.

For example, I want to do this:

1. Load the CSV into RAM as a table
2. Remove all rows where the field called transaction_type is recorded as "failed"
3. Save the result as a new CSV
4. Open the result as a workbook in Excel

My goal is to do this operation with the highest performance possible. I think that this functionality is provided by the [Extensible Storage Engine (ESE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg269259%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx), but I'm not sure how to use it through the Excel VBA IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need it fast you should probably consider doing the transformation in another language (c java ....) and only step 4 in vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 'text database' and use ADO (or DAO) to query the files. See this article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

That way you can just create a schema.ini file for the file you wish to query and query the file using standard SQL. You would then simply write your result recordset to file.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try, thanks! However, this is JET Red. I still would really to try out a JET Blue solution, I think it should be a lot faster.

Comment: I got it to work by using information on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) and changing  to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 (after installing [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255). Now, what's the best way to write the Recordset to CSV?

Comment: Actually, I can write it straight to an Excel spreadsheet, but I can't get OLEDB to guess the field types properly, so it gets copied to Excel as text. Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Is your schema.ini file setup correctly? That should define the datatypes of the fields which I would assume would be what gets put into Excel.

Comment: I haven't set one up. I figured out another solution for it, though. I made a script which loops through the columns and does a Text-To-Columns (without a delimiter), which determines the field type.

Comment: Still though, can I make it guess the field types?

Answer (score 1):

> > > I'm not sure how to use it through the Excel VBA IDE.

Even me :)

> > > > - Load the CSV into RAM as a table
> > > > - Remove all rows where the field called transaction_type is recorded as "failed"
> > > > - Save the result as a new CSV
> > > > - Open the result as a workbook in Excel

Here is an alternative.

- Load the CSV into Access Database from Excel using "**.TransferText**"

**Example Code**

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Set reference to Microsoft Access Object Library
Sub Sample()
    Dim oacApp As Access.Application

    Set oacApp = New Access.Application

    oacApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\MyDatabase.mdb"

    oacApp.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", _
    "Table1", "C:\Mycsv.csv", True

    oacApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    oacApp.Quit acQuitSaveNone

    Set oacApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

- Remove all rows where the field called transaction_type is recorded as "failed"

You can do that by running a query from excel.

- Save the result as a new CSV

Again use "**.TransferText**" to export it to CSV

**Example Code**

```
    oacApp.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Standard Output", _
    "Table1", "C:\MyNewcsv.csv"
```

- Open the result as a workbook in Excel

HTH

Comment: I'm aware about this option, but I wasn't satisfied with the performance I got in Access (JET Red). I really want to try to use the ESE (JET Blue). I'll take less features over higher performance.